# Need a postgresql query to group and order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a customers table as following:

```
customername, ordername, amount
=============================
bob, book,     20
bob, computer, 40
steve,hat,     15
bill, book,    12
bill, computer, 3
steve, pencil, 10
bill, pen,      2
```

I want to run a query to get the following result:

```
customername, ordername, amount
=============================
bob,   computer, 40
bob,   book,     20
bob,   ~total~,  60
steve, hat,      15
steve, pencil, 10
steve, ~total~,25 
bill, book,    12
bill, computer, 3
bill, pen,      2 
bill, ~total~, 17
```

I want the amount for each customer to be ordered from max to min and a new ordername as "~total~" (must always be the last row for each customer) with a result as sum of all amount for the same customer.
So, in above example, bob should be the first since the total=60, steve the second (total=25) and bill the third (total=17).

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
SELECT x.customername,
       x.ordername,
       x.amount
  FROM (SELECT a.customername,
               a.ordername,
               a.amount,
               y.rk,
               1 AS sort
          FROM CUSTOMERS a
          JOIN (SELECT c.customername,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(c.amount) DESC) AS rk
                  FROM CUSTOMERS c
              GROUP BY c.customername) y ON y.customername = a.customername
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.customername,
               '~total~',
               SUM(b.amount),
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(b.amount) DESC) AS rk,              
               2 AS sort
          FROM CUSTOMERS b
      GROUP BY b.customername) x
ORDER BY x.rk, x.customername, x.sort, x.amount DESC
```

You could look at using `GROUP BY ROLLUP`, but the `ordername` value would be NULL so you'd have to post-process it to get that replaced with "~total~"...

Comment: I like the "phantom column for sorting" idea. I was in the process of building a fancy ORDER BY that involved a comparison with `'~total~'`, but your way's much cleaner -- it works even if someone places an order named `'~total~'`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, it's still not ordering the amount column in descending order.

Comment: Adding x.amount DESC to the last line (ORDER BY x.customername, x.sort, x.amount DESC) orders in decending.

Thanks again

Comment: Now the last thing to be resolved is to show the max first. So, 
first bob, second steve and last bill.

Comment: "GROUP BY ROLLUP" doesn't exist in PostgreSQL. A window function will do the trick.